# Mailchimp API - Daily historical subscribers count/calculations

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I've been trying to calculate historic mailchimp list subscribers count by using the API and can't find an accurate way.

Obtaining current subscriber count is easy via getting list stats:
[Mailchimp list stats](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/#%20)

List Growth is only monthly:
[Mailchimp list Growth](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/growth-history/) , I want to obtain/calculate daily.

Tried using list activity: [Mailchimp List activity](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/activity/) but it doesn't add up to list growth for example unless I'm missing something/doing it wrong.

Has anyone tried to do something similar and succeeded?

Thanks

P.S. I've been doing this with python, although it doesn't matter for my question

Comment: I'm stuck with the same issue. Couldn't figure out a solution yet.